# How do I get this JSONP feed to update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to display JSONP data with $ & ajax in a div on a webpage.  I want this data to be updated regularly.  But the code below only displays the data once and then it never changes.  What can I do to get the data to display and then actually change when the information from the feed changes?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   setInterval(function refreshWeather() { 
   $(function() {
   $.ajax({
   url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/mykey/conditions/forecast/q/autoip.json",
   dataType : "jsonp",
   success : function(parsed_json) { 
   var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
   var feelslike = parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_f'];
   var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['date'];
   $('#content13').replaceWith(temp_f + " feels like " + feelslike);
     }
    });
    });
   }, 90000);

  </script>
```

Comment: jsonp url contains `callback` added in the url. Yours does not and your ajax code is missing the `type:"post/get",`

Comment: Why would anyone set `type` to `get`? That's the default

Comment: @Alexander it does support jsonp

Comment: @Musa, you're right. I just tried it.

Comment: @Jai, jQuery adds the "callback=?" if the dataType is "jsonp".

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$(function () {
    var refreshWeather = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/mykey/conditions/forecast/q/autoip.json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (parsed_json) {
                var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
                var feelslike = parsed_json['current_observation']['feelslike_f'];
                var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['date'];
                $('#content13').replaceWith(temp_f + " feels like " + feelslike);
            }
        });
    };

    refreshWeather();
    setInterval(refreshWeather, 90000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nsu3h/

Comment: `$(function() {...})` will fire the function immediately if the document is already loaded.

Comment: @musa, thank you for enlightening me. I found that in the documentation that I linked in my answer. D'oh!